# Automate flutter workflow using github actions

Tags: github, flutter, github-actions

I have a flutter project and am trying to automate using github actions. I want to create the apk as soon as I create a new tag and save the apk to it. Can someone help me?

```
on : push
name: build and test app
jobs:
  build:
    name: install dependencies
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: install dependencies
      uses: steebchen/flutter@v1.0.0
      with:
        args: pub get

 #   - name: run tests
  #    uses: steebchen/flutter@v1.0.0
   #   with:
    #    args: test

    - name: build apk
      uses: steebchen/flutter@v1.0.0
      with:
        args: build apk --release

#- uses: actions/checkout@master

    - uses: actions/download-artifact@master
      with:
        name: app-release.apk
        path: build/app/outputs/apk/release/

    - run: cat build/app/outputs/apk/release/
```

I can build it, but I can't download the artifact

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To use --release to have to set up the key store and signingConfigs on android. That was done? I've and app setup with Actions and kind-of-work (it fails because the app is using flutter dev channel and the image of actions use stable).

Try first using 'build apk --debug'

Also, use ls to look into a directory:

```
    - run: ls android/build/app/outputs/apk/release/
```

Comment: I can build it, but I can't download the artifact

Comment: I think that your problem is you miss the android folder in the apk path. Should be. android/build and no build/